# Drilling into UL with Jquery

Tags: jquery, menu

I have a UL List set up as follows:

```
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="step-1" />
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="step-2" />
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to drill into the "a href" in that list and change a class attribute and I am having some trouble.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick, can someone help steer me straight?

```
 var menuItem = $('#menu ul li').find('a:has(href="#step-'+num+'")');
 menuItem.removeClass('disabled');
 menuItem.addClass('done');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#menu ul li a[href^="step"]').removeClass('disabled').addClass('done');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CC7aa/2/)**

#### Note

`^=` is **[Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** selector, in this case it point out those `a` whose `href` start with `step`

#### In your approach

```
 var menuItem = $('#menu ul li').find('a[href^="step"]');
 menuItem.removeClass('disabled');
 menuItem.addClass('done');
```

#### According to fiddle share in comment

```
$('#wizard ul li a[href="#step-'+ step +'"]').removeClass('disabled').addClass('done');
```

not

```
$('#menu ul li a[href="#step-'+ step +'"]').removeClass('disabled').addClass('done');
```

There is nothing with `id=menu`, it is `id=wizard`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kBxUq/1/)**

Comment: @ackerchez please check my demo

Comment: @ackerchez it means `<a href="step-1" />` should `<a href="step-1"></a>`

Comment: use * or ^ it will make your day

Comment: @ackerchez why, can you make a fiddle and share

Comment: I have created a fiddle with what I am attempting to do. It is a wizard plugin that I am trying to change the selected item in the top row. There is no built method for that (sort of silly). Here is the fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/kBxUq/

Comment: @ackerchez your selector was wrong. it should `$('#wizard ul li a[href="#step-'+ step +'"]').removeClass('disabled').addClass('done')`. `#wizard` instead of `#menu`